# How can I test nested slots in Vue

Tags: vue.js, chai, vue-test-utils

I am trying to pass nested slots into my mounted component and I can;'t figure out the syntax, couldn't find anything in docs.

What I am trying to do is to add html element into drop-down slot
This is my test what I've tried but it looks to be wrong.

```
  it('should render drop down', async () => {    
    const wrapper = mount(MyComponent, {
      slots: {
        utilities: `
        <template slot="drop-down">
          <input placeholder="Search bar" class="header-bar-mobile-drop-down-utility__example">
        </template>
        `
      }
    });

    expect(wrapper.find(".header-bar-mobile-drop-down-utility").exists()).to.equal(true)
  });
```

Comment: Have you managed to find a solution?

Comment: yes pass slots in the wrapper,pass name of slots, this will mock things 

      slots: {
        'drop-down': '<div>Drop Down</div>'
      }